# How to get a list of values between two values without knowing which is greater in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a list of the values between x and y, not including x and y.  I'm aware range() can be used to accomplish this.  However, I need to be able to do this without knowing whether x or y is greater.

The main problems I'm running into are that range() does not seem to work when the first argument is greater, and I can't know whether to increment x or y in order to make sure x and y are not included.

I'm aware there's a way to do this in several lines with if statements and for loops, however I'm looking for a method that only takes one or two lines, perhaps with a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the min max function

```
for i in range(min(x,y)+1, max(x,y)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same answer I posted. Any modification should be suggested in the original answer's comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
for num in range(min(x, y), max(x, y)) 
   ... do something...
```

Comment: This nearly does the trick but I didn't want to include the minimum value in the range

Comment: @iceburger It was pretty straightforward from here.